# While running the protractor am getting the following error

Tags: protractor

[15:54:45] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:54:45] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4723/we/hub/status
[15:54:46] E/launcher - That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource
[15:54:46] E/launcher - UnsupportedOperationError: That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource

Comment: Please show us some code to help you. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, please provide code. For example, `protractor.conf.js` could be helpful here. Just paste the relevant related code.

Comment: Try using `http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/status` instead of `localhost`

Comment: show the `seleniumAddress` in your protractor.conf.js.  It should be like `http://<selenium server>:4444/wd/hub`